# What is the Win32 API LogFont.lfCharSet value for the "Unicode" character set?

Tags: winapi, unicode, fonts, character-encoding

I'm working on a legacy Delphi 6 / Nevrona Rave 4 application.  I have some reports which use the Code128A.ttf font.  They print to printers fine.  However, I am updating the program to generate PDF output using the TReportSystem.RenderObject, TRPRenderPDF.  The PDF is properly generated except for the Code128A fonts, which are displayed as ANSI.

My question is generic Win32 LogFont, not Delphi or Nevrona Rave.  A clue in the Nevrona documentation says that the TReportSystem.ReportPrinter.FontCharset needs to be set to the appropriate Win32 API LogFont.lfCharset byte for the font being used.

When I look at my Code128A.ttf font using the Windows CharacterMap application (in advanced mode), it tells me that the Character Set for my Code128A font is "Unicode".  It does not show me the corresponding lfCharset byte value.

Doe anyone know the lfCharset byte value to use with Unicode ttf fonts?

I'm hoping for an answer before I end up trying all of the pre-defined bytes, and if none of those work, try undefined ones.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `lfCharset` value defined for Unicode. That would defeat the purpose of specifying a charset in the first place. Use whichever charset the font actually implements. It looks like most of its barcode glyphs are available in most charsets (some charsets have a few less glyphs). So try setting the `lfCharset` to 0 (`ANSI_CHARSET`) or 1 (`DEFAULT_CHARSET`) if you must set a charset at all.

Comment: I tried all the pre-defined *_CHARSET values with mixed results.  Since the font works everywhere else it is used in the application, I am chalking this one up to being a bug in Nevrona's RAVE 4 TRPRenderPDF or TRPRender modules

Comment: Although your answer did not solve my problem, it did answer my question.   Debugging and modifying the RAVE 4 modules had mixed, but unacceptable results.  If I need barcodes in this case, I'll create them graphically by drawing the barcode to bitmap and then render the bitmap in the PDF generation process.  THANK YOU!

Comment: A comment for anyone reading this:  The version of Nevrona RAVE (4) that I am working with in this case is well past its support lifecycle.  The fact that I am working with legacy production systems that are still using it is a good indicator of the quality of Delphi and Nevrona software.  It is probable that current versions of these reporting components do not have this problem.